# WhatsApp cloud API is working in testing but how to use for production?

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

I already created permanent token but it's only able to send messages on testing numbers.
Is there any other configuration required before i use it for production and send messages to my customers ?

Comment: no, you need to add new number and add access of that system user to people in the newly added number (in menu Accounts > Whatsapp account).